# OpenVPN LAN routing

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, openvpn

I have a remote machine hosting both an OpenVPN server and an HTTP/S server, but when an OpenVPN client is connected and sends requests to the HTTP/S server (the public IP of the remote machine), it does not route thru the tunnel.

The OpenVPN server (relevant config parts):

```
proto udp
dev tun
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
topology subnet
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

And the routing tables:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

---

And from the client, traffic to remote server routing thru the tunnel (gateway=10.8.0.1):

```
$ traceroute ifconfig.co
traceroute to ifconfig.co (104.28.18.94), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  91.043 ms  92.079 ms  95.904 ms
 2  x.x.compute.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x)  106.990 ms  108.148 ms
 3  100.64.2.12 (100.64.2.12)  112.189 ms
    100.64.3.12 (100.64.3.12)  103.892 ms
    100.64.3.204 (100.64.3.204)  114.123 ms
...
```

However, when the client sends traffic to the VPN server's address it gets routed thru the client's LAN (gateway=192.168.100.1):

```
$ traceroute $SERVER_DNS
traceroute to $SERVER_DNS ($SERVER_IP), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1)  4.974 ms  8.735 ms  5.612 ms
 2  * * *
 3  x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)  15.093 ms  15.998 ms  31.362 ms
 4  x.oc.oc.cox.net (x.x.x.x)  54.835 ms  20.958 ms  21.883 ms
```

Comment: That's normal and expected. How else could your computer reach the VPN server?

Comment: Right, I see your point... I guess I expected the client to route all traffic thru tun interface _except_ for packets destined to the VPN server only on that port (e.g., 1194). What I see now on the client is: `add net ${VPN_IP}: gateway 192.168.100.1`. Thanks for helping me see this more clearly.